# Joining a table twice in sql with columns year and movie counts for imdb movie database

Tags: sql, self-join

i am joining a  same table with columns year and no_of_movies in that year with same table where year form first table should join with year from second table where second table year is less than first table year+9

my code is

```
SELECT b.YEAR  , b.Total_Movies,a.YEAR , a.Total_Movies
FROM (
    SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4) AS YEAR,YEAR+9 AS Decade ,COUNT(*) AS Total_Movies
    FROM Movie m
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4)) b,
    (SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4) AS YEAR,COUNT(*) AS Total_Movies
    FROM Movie m 
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4)) a
WHERE b.YEAR <=a.YEAR 
;
```

but i am not getting the output as required
the output im getting is

[image: output of my code]

The required output is

[image: output desired]

Comment: You're not using the `Decade` column in the joining condition.

Comment: I think it should be `WHERE b.decade <= a.year`

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: ```WHERE b.decade <= a.year``` not working

Comment: This alone `b.YEAR <=a.YEAR` isn't enough, you need the other condition too, `b.YEAR >a.YEAR-9` or something similar

Comment: i have used  `b.YEAR<= Decade `  with `b.YEAR <=a.YEAR` but it is returning empty table

Comment: Please specify the database product you are using.
Please specify your input data/table.
In the expression `SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(m.year),-4) AS YEAR,YEAR+9 AS Decade` the YEAR in YEAR+9 might be the original column value (I can't tell what it is) or the result of SUBSTR..., depending on the database product you are using. Try a different name.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you, you are trying to get each year combination but the difference between years shouldn't exceed the 9 years with count movies.
In other words, super simplified(obviously there might not be all years presented):

```
1901 | 1901
1901 | 1902
1901 | 1903
1901 | 1904
1901 | 1905
1901 | 1906
1901 | 1907
1901 | 1908
1901 | 1909
1901 | 1910
1902 | 1902
1902 | 1903
```

and so on...

I think there might be a room for the future optimisation, but that solution came to my mind firstly:

```
create table Movie(
  year date,
  title varchar(5)
);

insert into Movie
values
      ('1990-01-01', 'film1'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film4'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film5'), 
      ('1990-01-01', 'film6'), 
      ('1991-01-01', 'film1'), 
      ('1991-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('1991-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1992-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1992-01-01', 'film4'), 
      ('1993-01-01', 'film5'), 
      ('1994-01-01', 'film6'),
      ('1995-01-01', 'film1'), 
      ('1995-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('1995-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1995-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1995-01-01', 'film4'), 
      ('1995-01-01', 'film5'),
      ('1996-01-01', 'film1'), 
      ('1996-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('1997-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1997-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('1998-01-01', 'film4'), 
      ('1999-01-01', 'film5'),
      ('1999-01-01', 'film1'), 
      ('2000-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('2000-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('2000-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('2000-01-01', 'film2'), 
      ('2000-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('2001-01-01', 'film3'), 
      ('2003-01-01', 'film4'),
      ('2003-01-01', 'film4'),
      ('2003-01-01', 'film4'),
      ('2003-01-01', 'film4'),
      ('2004-01-01', 'film5');

select m2.year as Year, m2.cnt as Total_Movies, m1.year as Year, m1.cnt as Total_Movies
from (
   select Year(year) as year, count(*) as cnt 
        from Movie
        where Year(year) in (
                            select Year(year) + 9 as year
                            from Movie
                            group by Year(year) + 9
                           )
        group by Year(year)
     ) as m1
left join 
    (
        select YEAR(year) as year, count(*) as cnt
        from Movie
        group by Year(year)
    ) as m2
    /* to sutisfy your condition */
 on m1.year >= m2.year and (m1.year - m2.year <= 9)
order by m2.year asc;
```

It would be great if you could share more information about RDBMS, version, some input data and table schema you are using.
I am not sure that my data is accurate, nevertheless it holds the range in 9 years between.

Hope that helps or will give a hint for the solution.

[View on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f0acc/43)

Comment: @pasha, are you looking for another solution?